# Reading the headers of a CSV file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My CSV file consists of headers namely (DateTime,Samplevalue and hostname). 
And 
I want to read these headers and for instance, if the csv file consists of DateTime as it's header I want to print ( this is suitable for timeseries database) 
How to achieve this using angularjs ? 
How to code this ?

For instance, my CSV looks like

```
Hostname,Samplevalue,DateTime
Host1,1,2018-05-04 31:21:11
Host2,1,2018-05-05 21:15:10
Host3,1,2018-05-04 11:11:13
Host4,1,2018-05-06 41:21:15
```

Need to just read any one of the header  and print something like 
Console.log(datetime header is suitable fr this database)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide some more info. CSV's can vary, they can be comma or semicolon separated, they can have quoted strings or not ...What have you tried?

Comment: It's comma separated not semicolon. No they need not have quoted strings. I got code to read the csv BT I don't want that. Instead I want to read just the headers and print a text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wish to read the **CSV** data?

If yes, the best way to deal with **CSV** files in **JavaScript** is to convert it into **JSON** data.

Check out https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv, its a simple library where you can pass your CSV data and get JSON in return. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http` and 1) split the returned string by line breaks 2)
split the first line by commas :

```
$http.get('path/to/csv/').then(function(csv) {
  var headers = csv.data.split('\n')[0].split(',')
  headers.forEach(function(header, index) {
    console.log('header #'+index, header)
  })
})
```